Permission Denied and Python Module Issues when Deploying Django with Apache on Ubuntu
I'm encountering difficulties while trying to deploy my Django website using Apache on an Ubuntu server. Here are the details of the problem:
Error Messages:
Current thread 0x00007e9faacab780 (most recent call first):
<no Python frame>
[Thu Jun 27 02:58:10.538441 2024] [wsgi:warn] [pid 16762:tid 139224230311808] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=16762): Unable to stat Python home /home/robch/TestSite/django_env. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Python path configuration:
PYTHONHOME = '/home/robch/TestSite/django_env'
PYTHONPATH = (not set)

Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'

and when i go to my page i see and error 403: 
here is some more information about my files:
(django_env) robch@django-server:~$ ls -la
total 44
drwxr-x---  6 robch robch    4096 Jun 27 01:44 .
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root     4096 Jun 26 21:58 ..
-rw-------  1 robch robch    1102 Jun 27 00:08 .bash_history
-rw-r--r--  1 robch robch     220 Jun 26 21:58 .bash_logout
-rw-r--r--  1 robch robch    3771 Jun 26 21:58 .bashrc
drwx------  3 robch robch    4096 Jun 26 23:45 .cache
-rw-------  1 robch robch      20 Jun 27 01:44 .lesshst
drwxrwxr-x  3 robch robch    4096 Jun 26 22:21 .local
-rw-r--r--  1 robch robch     807 Jun 26 21:58 .profile
drwx------  2 robch robch    4096 Jun 26 22:56 .ssh
-rw-r--r--  1 robch robch       0 Jun 26 22:43 .sudo_as_admin_successful
drwxrwxr-x 13 robch www-data 4096 Jun 27 02:51 TestSite
(django_env) robch@django-server:~$ cd TestSite/ && ls -la
total 300
drwxrwxr-x 13 robch    www-data   4096 Jun 27 02:51 .
drwxr-x---  6 robch    robch      4096 Jun 27 01:44 ..
drwxrwxr-x  8 robch    robch      4096 Jun 26 23:47 .git
-rw-rw-r--  1 robch    robch         6 Jun 26 23:39 README.md
drwxrwxr-x  3 robch    robch      4096 Jun 27 02:23 Soundrise
drwxrwxr-x  5 robch    robch      4096 Jun 26 23:39 accounts
drwxrwxr-x  4 robch    robch      4096 Jun 26 23:39 beatmakers
drwxrwxr-x  5 robch    robch      4096 Jun 26 23:39 beats
drwxrwxr-x  4 robch    robch      4096 Jun 26 23:39 content
-rw-rw-r--  1 robch    www-data 241664 Jun 27 00:59 db.sqlite3
drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data   4096 Jun 27 02:51 django_env
drwxrwxr-x  5 robch    robch      4096 Jun 26 23:39 files
-rw-rw-r--  1 robch    robch       665 Jun 26 23:39 manage.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 robch    robch        80 Jun 26 23:47 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x  4 www-data www-data   4096 Jun 26 23:56 static
drwxrwxr-x  4 robch    robch      4096 Jun 26 23:39 transaction
drwxrwxr-x  4 robch    robch      4096 Jun 26 23:39 utils

(django_env) robch@django-server:~/TestSite$ cat /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/TestSite.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        ServerName 85.215.209.167

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf

        Alias /static /home/robch/TestSite/static
        <Directory /home/robch/TestSite/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /media /home/robch/TestSite/files/media
        <Directory /home/robch/TestSite/files/media>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        <Directory /home/robch/TestSite/Soundrise>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/robch/TestSite/Soundrise/wsgi.py
        WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-home=/home/robch/TestSite/django_env python-path=/home/robch/TestSite
        WSGIProcessGroup django_app

</VirtualHost>
(django_env) robch@django-server:~/TestSite$

Steps Taken:

Checked and adjusted permissions for /home/robch/TestSite/django_env.
Verified Python installation within the virtual environment (/home/robch/TestSite/django_env).
Reviewed Apache configuration (*.conf files in /etc/apache2/sites-available/) to ensure correct python-home and python-path directives.

Request for Assistance:
How can I have my site FINALLLY displaying.
What steps should I take to ensure Python within the virtual environment has all necessary modules, especially 'encodings'?

Your whole home folder is inaccessible by Apache. Not a programming issue though.

Using apache in your home directory is not a fun time. The error message ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings' hints that python can find its main executable, but can't find some built-in modules. This could either because of permissions or because python was not installed properly (at least for apache). Try installing the project outside of home (with a new venv and all).

Solution:
The problem is due to Apache not having permission to access your home directory. Here's how to fix it:
Create a New Directory:
sudo mkdir /var/www/TestSite
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data /var/www/TestSite
sudo chmod -R 775 /var/www/TestSite

Move Your Project:
mv ~/TestSite /var/www/

Update Apache Configuration:
Update /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/TestSite.conf:
apache conf:
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 85.215.209.167
    DocumentRoot /var/www/TestSite

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    Alias /static /var/www/TestSite/static
    <Directory /var/www/TestSite/static>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    Alias /media /var/www/TestSite/files/media
    <Directory /var/www/TestSite/files/media>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/TestSite/Soundrise>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            Require all granted
        </Files>
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/TestSite/Soundrise/wsgi.py
    WSGIDaemonProcess django_app python-home=/var/www/TestSite/django_env python-path=/var/www/TestSite
    WSGIProcessGroup django_app
</VirtualHost>


Restart Apache:
sudo systemctl restart apache2
By moving your project out of the home directory and ensuring proper permissions, the deployment issues should be resolved.
